# Game Maker attack wont work

Tags: c#, gml

When I press the x keyboard button, my player sprite won't attack for some reason. Is there anything I can do to help my sprite player to do an attack?

/// Obj_player Create Event

```
/// set fixed rotation for object player
event_inherited();
hp = 20;
spd = 4;
hspd = 0;
vspd = 0;
len = 0;
xaxis = 0;
yaxis = 0;
dir = 0;
attacked = false;
image_speed = 0;
scr_get_input();
state = scr_move_state;
```

/// Obj_player Alarm 0

```
/// This alarm is for the dash state
state = scr_dash_state;
state = scr_attack_state;
```

///Obj_player Step Event

```
/// move the player in the step event
event_inherited();
script_execute(state);
state = scr_move_state;
scr_get_input();
```

/// Obj_Animation End

```
/// Change back to move state
if (state == scr_attack_state)  {
    state = scr_move_state;
    attacked = false;
}
```

/// scr_get_input

```
right_key = keyboard_check(vk_right);
left_key = keyboard_check(vk_left);
up_key = keyboard_check(vk_up);
down_key = keyboard_check(vk_down);
dash_key = keyboard_check_pressed(ord('C'));
attack_key = keyboard_check_pressed(ord('X'));

// Get the axis
xaxis = (right_key - left_key);
yaxis = (down_key - up_key);
```

/// scr_move_state

```
scr_get_input();

if (dash_key)   {
    state = scr_dash_state;
    alarm[0] = room_speed/7;
}

if (attack_key) {
    image_index = 0;
    state = scr_attack_state;
}

// get direction
dir = point_direction(0,0, xaxis, yaxis);

// Get the length
if (xaxis == 0 and yaxis = 0)   {
    len = 0;
} else {
    len = spd;
}

// Get the hspd and vspd
hspd = lengthdir_x(len, dir);
vspd = lengthdir_y(len, dir);

// move 
phy_position_x += hspd;
phy_position_y += vspd;

// Control the sprite
image_speed = sign(len)*.2;
if (len == 0) image_index = 0;

// Vertical sprites
if (vspd > 0) {
    sprite_index = spr_player_down;
} else if (vspd < 0)    {
    sprite_index = spr_player_up;
}

// Horizontal sprites
if (hspd > 0) {
    sprite_index = spr_player_right;
} else if (hspd < 0)    {
    sprite_index = spr_player_left;
}
```

/// scr_attack_state

```
image_speed = .5;

switch (sprite_index)    {
    case spr_player_down:
        sprite_index = spr_player_attack_down;
        break;

    case spr_player_up:
        sprite_index = spr_player_attack_up;
        break;

    case spr_player_right:
        sprite_index = spr_player_attack_right;
        break;

    case spr_player_left:
        sprite_index = spr_player_attack_left;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in this line:

```
attack_key = keyboard_check_pressed(ord('X'));
```

You assigned attack_key to X, which is different from x. It should be:

```
attack_key = keyboard_check_pressed(ord('x'));
```

Comment: I thought I had to use X instead of x keyboard button for an attack to work.

Comment: I made the X caption letter to lower case letter and didn't make any changes.

Comment: I try to use the same solution for my dash in Obj_player's Alarm 0 event.